# What exactly is a "boogy ride"?

Tags: american-english, history

Cartoon video source: https://archive.org/details/merriemelodiescoalblackanddesebbendwarfs1943

Title: "**Coal Black and de Sebben Dwarfs**" (1943)

At **03:32**, So White goes:

> Well, thanks for the **boogy ride**!

followed by something I can't make out.

What is a "boogy ride"? From the context, my assumption is "the pleasurable ride" or "the joyful ride", but I've never heard that term before and was unable to look it up.

Comment: Take a look at [**Boogie rides**](https://www.google.com/search?q=boogy+ride&tbm=isch&nfpr=1&rlz=1C1ARAB_enBR495BR495&hl=en&ved=2ahUKEwiz6r7L_dnnAhUED9QKHWtgCFAQvgV6BAgBECk&biw=1519&bih=731#imgrc=dQ8KrjdHR2cOgM)